# Pycharm issuing an error

Tags: python-2.7, unix, pycharm

This is the code in question:

```
#i/p from user   
print "enter your number"  
a=sys.stdin.readline()  

if(a==6):  
    print('entered a 6!')  
else:    
    print('you did not enter a 6')
```

If I enter `6`, it is supposed to return `entered a 6!`,but it is returning `you did not enter a 6`.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

`a = int(sys.stdin.readline())`

or

`a = int(raw_input())`

Your code is reading the input as a string, and you are comparing it to an integer. You need to convert the input for `a` to an `int` before making the comparison.

Comment: This is the correct answer. This is called ["type conversion", "type casting" or "type coercion"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion)

Comment: Thank you so much!!